# Getting substring between nth and mth occurence of some sequence

Tags: python

I want to do search a string that I know contains several occurences of a particular char sequence and retrieve what's between two certain of these occurences, numbered. Or preferably, numbered from the end. I also want to do this as compact as possible, as it goes inside a list comprehension.

Let's say I have the following string:

```
s = "foofoo\tBergen, Norway\tAffluent\tDonkey"
```

I want to retrieve the substring of s that is situated between the last occurence of `"\t"` and the penultimate occurence.

So in this very example: `"Affluent"`

Here is the comprehension I am currently using (without having pruned the string):

```
data = [(entries[i], entries[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(entries), 3)]
```

It's the string `entries[i]` for every entry into data that I want to prune.

Comment: What output are you expecting to get in your list comprehension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rsplit` is used to split the word from right side

```
a="foofoo\tBergen, Norway\tAffluent\tDonkey"

word= a.rsplit('\t',2)
if len(word)>2:
     print word[-2]

#output =Affluent
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `split` the string by your character sequence, and `join` back-together (using your character sequence as the joining string) the desired occurrences.

***Update***:For the example cited:

```
"\t".join(s.split("\t")[-2:-1])
```

Comment: Can I do this in one line? I'll update the question with the comprehension where I want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the beginning of your string is treated as the 0th occurrence of the delimeter symbol:

```
def concat_strings(strs):
    result = ""
    for substr in strs:
        result = result + substr
    return result

def find_section(s, delim, n, m):
    tokens = s.split(delim)
    return concat_strings(tokens[n:m])
```